# Найти "лишнее" слово

Tags: словообразование

Какой из глаголов "лишний" и почему?
недоглядеть, недосыпать, недоговаривать, недолюбливать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Если второй глагол о сне (а не о недосыпанном сахаре), то "лишний" глагол - "недоглядеть": он совершенного вида, в отличие от остальных.
2. В смысловом отношении выделяется глагол "недолюбливать": остальные глаголы выражают недостаточную интенсивность или незаконченность действия, а этот - метафорически выражает отрицание связанного с корнем глагола действия (= относиться плохо - в смягчённой форме).

Comment: Так "недоглядеть" — тоже глагол совершенного вида, Александр.

Comment: Я только его и выделил (отсеяв вариант "недосЫпать").

Comment: Ой, простите, Александр, невнимательно прочитал, показалось "если НЕ о сне", а у Вас как раз "О сне".

Answer (score 3):

Как вариант: ***недолюбливать*** -- *несов.*, **видовой пары не имеет**.

Остальные из представленных глаголов *(недоглядеть, недосыпать, недоговаривать)* **видовую пару имеют**.

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю, что *лишним* в этом квартете глаголов будет *недосыпать*. Потому что в большей мере, чем остальные, этот глагол характеризует состояние, а не действие; кроме того, здесь направленность характеристики внутренняя, а у остальных она в большей мере внешняя.

Answer (score 2):

Наверное, глагол "недолюбливать", так как слово изменило свое значение: недолюбливать - это не мало (недостаточно) любить, а не любить вовсе, относиться не лучшим образом.
В других словах приставка НЕДО имеет значение недостаточности, например: недосыпать - спать мало.